# Как можно поместить zoomControl справа, сохраняя адаптивность размера?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Потому как если задать так:

```
      options = {
        position: {
          top: "108px",
          right: "10px",
          bottom: "auto",
          left: "auto"
        }
      };
```

то теряется адаптивность размера.

Comment: У меня вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/naivv/a0mp2qy4/ контрол всегда на своем месте остается.

Answer (score 0):

Я поставил зум справа вот так. Все всегда на своих местах:

```
myMap = new ymaps.Map("mod_map_material_map", {
    zoom: 10,              
    controls: ['zoomControl']
},{
    // Зададим опции для элементов управления.
    zoomControlPosition: { right: 10, top: 50 },
    zoomControlSize: 'small'
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но Вы принудительно поставили size=small. А мне нужно, чтобы при большой высоте карты был полный размер контрола, а при малой высоте, соответственно, малый.

Comment: Поставьте `zoomControlSize: 'auto'`